# LCCT Terminal in Kuala Lumper - Operating Hours

Tags: airports, kuala-lumpur, kul

I have a flight from BKK that arrives at the low cost carrier terminal in KL at 23:25 but my next flight to Vientiane isn't until 7:35 the next morning.  Does the terminal stay open overnight?

I don't think it is worth getting a hotel for such a short period of time.

Answer (score 4):

I believe both the main and low cost terminals at KUL are open 24 hours. I can't spot anything on the [LCCT terminal website](http://lcct.klia.com.my/) indicating otherwise. (The main terminal is definitely 24 hours)

For an overnight layover like that, you might want to consider just buying access to the [Plaza Premium Lounge in the LCCT](http://www.plaza-network.com/index.php/locations/malaysia/kuala-lumpur.html). That'll get you a shower, some food and drink, wifi (normally better than the airport wifi), and a comfy seat to snooze in. I've not used the LCCT one, but I've seen lots of people doing that same thing in the one in the main lounge!

If you do decide to buy access (assuming you don't get free access via one of the few airport lounge access programs, or some higher end credit cards), it's worth booking online in advance. You can normally manage a decent discount over the walk-in prices.

Answer (score 2):

[sleepinginairports.com](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/kualalumpur.htm#.UT8aztGfmft) indicates that Kuala Lumpur airport stays open 24h. However, from the reviews, it is suggested you take the shuttle to the other terminal (KLIA), which costs less than $1US since accommodations are better and thus you may be more comfortable.

Comment: Thank you for the replies!  OK I think I will be right now!

Comment: @John: You're welcome! Please make sure to upvote and/or accept hepful answers!